# Is there a way to re-balance the regions of a single table in Apache Hbase.

Tags: hbase

I have a 3 node Hbase cluster with 12 tables. But the regions of one of the tables are in the same RegionServer. Hence that table and ultimately that RegionServer is getting loaded as it is read intensive table. I am looking for a way to rebalance the regions of the single table. I know that Hbase does balancing by default but that is based on total number of regions and not the regions of a specific table.

Also, if not that what other strategies can be followed to achieve that. Would be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: HBase balancer didnt work but then when i ran HDFS balancer, things took shape and the regions got balanced. Weird.

Comment: So little update here. There is no direct way of balancing regions of the table automatically. One can manually move regions across region servers based on the load using the 'move' command on hbase shell.